# Return from background relaunches the entire app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms app, and I want to avoid a scenario where the startup flow has ended, all the data was loaded and displayed, and when the app goes to background and return, the same screen before going to background will be displayed instead of going all over the startup process again.

As far as I see, each time the app returns from background, `MainActivity` calls method `OnCreate`, which initiates all the startup process.

Comment: How do you background your app? I can't reproduce your issue. Which flags do you have on your MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

There were some bugs in Xamarin.Forms (I don't know if they were fixed). Dirty hack is:

```net
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (this.ActionBar.Title == "YourMainMenuTitle")
            {
                if (keyCode == Keycode.Back && e.RepeatCount == 0)
                {
                    MoveTaskToBack(true);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
        }

        // ...
    }
```

More here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/89844